# Ruby on Rails - production mode - search is not looking for the first letter of contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search page in my application. In development mode, it's working how it should be. But when I tried in production mode, some of the results are missing. In production mode, the search is not checking the first letters while doing a search. I thought it might be because I am somehow changing the search term but I checked it and there is no problem with it.

here are my model-related scopes:

```
scope :anime_list, -> { where(category: 'anime') }
scope :manga_list, -> { where(category: 'manga') }
scope :name_contains, -> (term) { where('name LIKE ?', "%#{term}%") }
scope :tag_contains, -> (term) { where('tags LIKE ?', "%#{term}%") }
scope :search, ->(search_term) { name_contains(search_term).or(tag_contains(search_term)) }
```

here is my related search action:

```
@search_term = params[:q]
if(@search_term)
  @animes = Content.all.search(@search_term).anime_list
  @mangas = Content.all.search(@search_term).manga_list
end
```

For example; I have animes and mangas in my application and you can search them via their name or tags. I have 'Naruto', 'Darling in the Franxx'. When I typed 'na' as a search term. Only 'Darling in the Franxx' is displaying. If I will search for something like 'aru', Naruto is displaying as well.

I have checked the logs of production and development mode when I made a search with the same search terms, they're the same. My question is, how can I add back the first letters to the search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the `LIKE` operator in Sqlite is case IN-sensitive which is not the case for Postgres.

You can fix this by using the `ILIKE` operator from Postgres, making the search work case in-sensitively as well.

```rb
scope :name_contains, -> (term) { where('name ILIKE ?', "%#{term}%") }
```

---

*As a side note I would recommend using the same database in development as in production, will save you many headaches.*